# V-If inside V-for, inside V-for

Tags: json, vue.js, v-for

I am a newbie with Vue and I am trying to run an IF statement inside two v-fors.
Basically I am trying to compare a value from one array of objects to a value of another array of objects and if true, render value from array of objects No 2.

Here is the code.

```
      <div v-bind:class="[isActive ? 'projectsWorkingOnActive' : 'projectsWorkingOnInactive']" v-for="rec in listOfEmployees" v-bind:key="rec.id" >
        <div v-for="proj in dummyProjectsData" v-bind:key="proj.id">
          <div v-if="rec.name.display_value == proj.task_owner">
            <h3>Projects Working On</h3>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">{{proj.projects_working_on.project_name}}</a></li>
              <li><submitbutton button_label="Hide Projects" @click="toggleClass()"></submitbutton></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And here are my 2 arrays of objects.

```
    const dummyProjectsData = [
  {
    ID: "44000005501077",
    task_owner: "Denis Denchev",
    projects_working_on: [
      {
      "project_name": "Project-1",
      "project_id": "195000002362044"
      },
      {
      "project_name": "Project-2",
      "project_id": "195000002362045"
      },
      {
      "project_name": "Project-3",
      "project_id": "195000002362046"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    ID: "44000005501078",
    task_owner: "Jake Jones",
    projects_working_on: [
      {
      "project_name": "Project-2",
      "project_id": "195000002362044"
      },
      {
      "project_name": "Project-5",
      "project_id": "195000002362045"
      },
      {
      "project_name": "Project-3",
      "project_id": "195000002362046"
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

And the second array...

```
 const listOfEmployees = [
  {
    "ID": "44000005527013",
    "name": {
     "display_value": "Denis Denchev",
     "first_name": "Denis",
     "last_name": "Denchev",
     "prefix": "",
     "suffix": "",
    }
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? It must be something silly that I am missing? Or can I not do if statement taking value from two v-for's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `proj.projects_working_on` is an array of multiple projects, but you are trying to access a property on it like an object.  Change to something like:

```html
<div v-bind:class="[isActive ? 'projectsWorkingOnActive' : 'projectsWorkingOnInactive']" v-for="rec in listOfEmployees" v-bind:key="rec.id" >
  <div v-for="proj in dummyProjectsData" v-bind:key="proj.id">
    <div v-if="rec.name.display_value == proj.task_owner">
      <h3>Projects Working On</h3>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="p in proj.projects_working_on" v-bind:key="p.project_id">
           <a href="">{{ p.project_name }}</a>
        </li>
        <li><submitbutton button_label="Hide Projects" @click="toggleClass()"></submitbutton></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```